# Erlang ASN.1 otp compile 'PKCS7' module p7b file to pem

Tags: ssl, openssl, erlang, erlang-otp, asn.1

I want to encode p7b file with certificate chain to pem
I can do it in console with `openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in certificate.p7b -out certificate.cer`
I want to do it with erlang ssl library - looks like otp should already do this without asn.1 [test in erlang otp](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/d6285b0a347b9489ce939511ee9a979acd868f71/lib/asn1/test/test_modified_x420.erl#L30)
But

```
1> application:ensure_all_started(ssl).
{ok,[crypto,asn1,public_key,ssl]}
```

But `PKCS7` module undefined - asn.1 was not compiled

```
2>  'PKCS7':decode('SignedData', Der1).              
** exception error: undefined function 'PKCS7':decode/2
```

If I download [PKCS7.asn](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/asn1/test/asn1_SUITE_data/modified_x420/PKCS7.asn) manually and try to compile, I'll get error

```
3> asn1ct:compile('PKCS7.asn')
PKCS7:13: 'Attribute' is not exported from InformationFramework
...
{error,[{structured_error,{'PKCS7',13},
                          asn1ct_check,
                          {undefined_import,'Attribute','InformationFramework'}},
        {structured_error,{'PKCS7',13},
```

Question 1: Is there any way to compile 'PKCS7' without manual downloading asn.1 modules? I am sure I missed something important, and this file should works automatically as otp lib

Question 2: Maybe there are some simplest way to encode p7b to pem chain?

Is there any documentation for using otp/lib/asn.1?

Answer (score 2):

There are no need to compile ANS.1 module PKCS7. The Erlang (Elixir) function `public_key:der_decode/2` works with `'ContentInfo'` atom as the first argument ASN1Type.

(elixir code)

```
{:ContentInfo, _id, content_info} = :public_key.der_decode(:ContentInfo, p7b_binary)
{:certSet, certificates_set} = elem(content_info, 4)
```

But question why `'PKCS7':decode` does not works still open

Comment: Can you add some explanation around this code? Your answer looks like it was [flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24013584)

Comment: Sure, it works without additional compiling ASN.1 modules